# In the storm Vs. by the storm

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, passive-voice

> - your hanging flower pots might get blown down **in this storm**.

Could we use “by storm” instead of “in storm” ?

Since the storm could blow down something, I think, it means we can use “by storm” in passive?

Don’t you agree?

Could you tell me the difference between “by the storm” and “in the storm”?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on what you want to express:

- If you want to express what sort of weather or even will **cause** the flower pots to get blown down, you would use **by the storm**. It is the storm that "does" this.
- If you want to express in what kind of **circumstances** this will happen, you can say **in the storm**. In that case, you are not saying that the storm will blow the flower pots down, but that this will happen during the storm.

Answer (score 2):

Both are **correct**. When you say that the pot was blown **by** the storm, it means that the storm has **caused something to happen**, which in this case means that the hanging pot may be blown off. However, technically the pot needs to be **in** the storm for it to be blown away.

> The most common preposition to use in this sentence would have to be '**by**', similar to how you would say 'Getting **on** the bus' as opposed to 'Getting **in** the bus'.
>   You could decide to be technical about the sentence, or say it in a more often and casual way. Best of luck.

Comment: *In* the storm might also refer to duration, i.e. *during the storm*, like *in the night* or *in the Nineties*.